# Book series about a paraplegic?

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

When I was younger I read a book series, possibly only a trilogy, about a boy who was confined to a wheelchair. he was transported to another world somehow, I can't remember. he meets this girl and they have to save their land or something. does this ring a bell? He might also possibly be using braces instead of a wheelchair I'm not sure.

It was in English. I know that much. One of the covers had blue people coming out of a wave or the ocean. I think the main characters name started with a J. I most likely read this book from 2008 to 2010.

The main characters name might be Kip or Kit, those are both ringing a bell. And I know that in the beginning he talks about feeling invisible.

Comment: When were you "younger" - or roughly speaking, when did you read the book? Do you remember any names or descriptions of other characters? Was the book geared towards any age group/audience? What language was it in? Do you remember the cover at all? Even tiny details could help us find this.

Comment: Was it a fantasy world that they go to? Sci-fi? Contemporary alternate world?

Comment: It was in English. I know that much. One of the covers had blue people coming out of a wave or the ocean. I think the main characters name started with a J. I most likely read this book from 2008 to 2010. @phantom42 and the world they went to was like magical. definitely fantasy

Comment: The *Tir Na Nog* trilogy largely match, Conor Kelly in a wheelchair in a world of Irish mysticism, except that they were released in 2013. The *Guardians of the Flame* includes a young man with muscular dystrophy and a wheelchair, set to a Fantasy World. The man in the wheelchair is James and the main character is Karl. Maybe you got the two confused?

Comment: Heh. And another letter/gender-swapped one, *[Silverdream and Bloodfire](http://www.webook.com/project/Silverdream-Bloodfire)* is about a girl named Amanda Jennings who has spina bifida and is in a wheelchair, and winds up going to a fantasy world where she allies with Prince Kelvan.

Comment: Neither of those sound right, but thank you for trying to help! It means a lot. @SeanDuggan

Answer (score 4):

Per OPs [own comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82984/book-series-about-a-paraplegic#comment178913_82985), this is [Farworld - Book 1: Water Keep](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1609073304)

> Even though thirteen-year-old Marcus Kanenas is confined to a
>   wheelchair, he sees himself as a survivor and a dreamer. In fact, his
>   favorite dream is of a world far away, a world where magic is as
>   common as air, where animals tell jokes, and where trees beg people to
>   pick their fruit. He even has a name for this place Farworld. When
>   Marcus magically travels to Farworld, he meets Kyja, a girl without
>   magic in a world where spells, charms, and potions are everywhere, and
>   Master Therapass, a master wizard who has kept a secret hidden for
>   thirteen years, a secret that could change the fate of two worlds. But
>   the Dark Circle has learned of Master Therapass’s secret and their
>   evil influence and power are growing. Farworld’s only hope is for
>   Marcus and Kyja to find the mythical Elementals water, land, air, and
>   -fire and convince them to open a drift between the worlds. As Kyja and Marcus travel to Water Keep, they must face the worst the evil
>   Dark Circle can throw at them Summoners, who can command the living
>   and the dead; Unmakers, invisible creatures that can destroy both body
>   and soul; and dark mages known as Thrathkin S Bae. Along the way,
>   Marcus and Kyja will discover the truth about their own heritage, the
>   strength of their friendship, and the depths of their unique powers.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Possibly William Sleator's *[The Last Universe](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0810992132)*?

> Susan and her wheelchair-bound brother, Gary, discover a mysterious maze in the vast gardens of their isolated home. Planted by a scientist uncle who disappeared long ago, the maze offers seemingly endless routes and choices. The teenagers discover that each turn they take alters their world in some way. Sickly Gary sees a chance to change his fate; Susan sees that they may both be lost forever

It has a boy in a wheelchair and a girl, and alternate worlds, but it doesn't match exactly. It's not a series and Gary and Susan know each other before traveling.

Comment: I FOUND IT THE BOOK IS CALLED FARWORLD. http://www.amazon.com/Farworld-Book-1-Water-Keep/dp/1609073304

Comment: @BradyKruegerJr:
Excellent. If you can accept Richard's reporting of your answer, we can close this all out. :)